# Expected value of room enters

Tags: probability

I was looking at previous exam questions, but one of the questions I don't know how to solve correctly.

In this question I need to calculate the expected amount of rooms the mouse enters before he is eaten by a cat. Each time the mouse has a p=$\frac{1}{2}$ of going right or left, but every time he enters a room, he forgots were he came from. So he can walk forever. The only problem that if he enters the room with the cat, he will be eaten by the cat, so he will stop there.

This was the image that belongs to the questions:

[image]

For exampe the mouse can enter the rooms in the following order: 1,2,1,0. The expected room enters will be 4.

In this question the expected of room enters is also 4. I calculated this, by looking at every room has the same probability to be entered and n=5. And you have a $\frac{1}{5}$ probability of entering room 0. So 4 rooms is the expected rooms I will enter, but the problem with this solution is that I can't use it to so solve harder questions. I need to use a formula to solve it, but I don't understand what formula. I hope that someone could show me correct way of solving this.

Comment: What happens after the mouse enters the room with the cheese? Does he stay there, does he go back to room 3 with probability 1, or is there a room 5 so the mouse can still go left with probability $\frac12$?

Comment: No, there is no room 5. He will just keep on walking till he get at the cat.

Comment: So after reaching room 4, the mouse has a Pr=1 of going to room 3 ? Which means that "every room has the same probability to be entered" is not true ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was wrong.

Comment: You might see Question 853308 on this site, were a similar problem is answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Markov Chain with state space $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\},$
in which state $0$ is is absorbing, and the other three states
are transient. Write the transition matrix. The text or lectures
for this course should show a method for determining the 'mean
time to absorption' starting at various transient states. 
You want the mean time to absorption starting at state 2.
(Depending on the text, the notation might be
something like $m_{2,0},\,$
$M_{20},\,$ or $\mu_{20}.$)

I am not giving the solution because (a) I think you will learn
something from looking up the method I mentioned, and (b) without
more background to use as a foundation, I don't know which of
several methods (or presentations of methods in terms of notation) is appropriate
to your level. Among the possibilities are: solution to a system of
linear equations, inverting a matrix, and multiple simulations
of the chain.